# 2D numerical integration with infinite limit (C++)

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

In order to integrate a two dimensional function of the form

```
$$\int_{1}^\infty \int_{-\sqrt{x^2-1}}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}} e^{-x} \rm{d}y \rm{d}x,$$
```

I have been attempting to use the following code (written in C++) taken mostly from the Numerical Recipes book which calls a gaussian quadrature routine for the integration:

```
 static float xsav;
 static float (*nrfunc)(float,float);

 float quad2d(float (*func)(float, float), float x1, float x2)
 {
     float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
     float f1(float x);

     nrfunc=func;
     return qgaus(f1,x1,x2); 
 }

 float f1(float x) 
 {
     float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
     float f2(float y);
     float yy1(float),yy2(float);

     xsav=x;
     return qgaus(f2,yy1(x),yy2(x)); 
 }

 float f2(float y)  
 {
     return (*nrfunc)(xsav,y);
 }
```

This code works fine for two dimensional integrals with finite limits, but fails as the outer limit is taken to infinity. To account for this, I have attempted to use a change of variables:

```
#define FUNC(x) ((*funk)(-log(x))/(x))

float qgaus(float (*funk)(float), float aa, float bb)
{
    int j;
    float xr,xm,dx,s,a,b;

    b=exp(-aa); 
    a=0.0;

    static float x[]={0.0,0.1488743389,0.4333953941,
        0.6794095682,0.8650633666,0.9739065285};
    static float w[]={0.0,0.2955242247,0.2692667193, 
        0.2190863625,0.1494513491,0.0666713443};

    xm=0.5*(b+a); 
    xr=0.5*(b-a);
    s=0;
    for (j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {
        dx=xr*x[j];
        s += w[j]*(FUNC(xm+dx)+FUNC(xm-dx)); 
    }
    return s *= xr; 
}


float f(float x, float y)
{
    float a = exp(-x);
    return a;
}

float yy1(float x)
{
    float y = -sqrt(x*x-1);
    return y;   
}

float yy2(float x)
{
    float y = sqrt(x*x-1);
    return y;
}



static float xsav;
static float (*nrfunc)(float, float);

float quad2d(float (*func)(float, float), float x1, float x2)
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float aa, float bb);
    float f1(float x);

    nrfunc=func;
    float t = qgaus(f1,x1,x2);
    return t;
}

float f1(float x)
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float aa, float bb);
    float f2(float y);
    float yy1(float);
    float yy2(float);

    xsav=x;
    float r = qgaus(f2,yy1(x),yy2(x));
    return r;
}

float f2(float y) 
{
    float k = (*nrfunc)(xsav,y);
    return k;
}

int main ()
{
    float z;
    z = quad2d(f, 1.0, 20.0);
    cout << z << endl;
}
```

but this still doesn't give the right answer. It should be

```
$2 \times \rm{BesselK}[1,1] \approx 1.20381$
```

but instead gives

```
2.15501
```

Any suggestions on how I could modify this code to account for the infinite limit would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your functions have unused variables: `In function 'float qgaus(float (*)(float), float, float)':
 warning: unused parameter 'bb'
...........
In function 'float f(float, float)':
 warning: unused parameter 'y'` Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. As stated in Numerical Recipes, "bb is assumed to be infinite (value passed not actually used)." I'm not sure why it says that 'y' is an unused parameter though.

Comment: Because the function `f` accepts two parameters (`x` and `y`), but only does this: `float a = exp(-x);`

Comment: Yeah, from what you've written, f is constant in y. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am aware. The function I am integrating is "exp(-x)dydx", where the limits on 'y' are functions of x. Whether I write "float f(float x, float y)" or "float f(float x)" does not change the incorrect result it keeps producing.

Comment: So really, this is a single integral w.r.t. x of the function 2 exp(-x) sqrt(x^2 - 1)?

Comment: Yes, this integral is easily solved analytically. It is simply a modified bessel function of the second kind. This is not the point. Writing code to solve "exp(-x) sqrt(x^2 - 1)" numerically is easy and I have already done it, but this is not what I need. What I need is code that will solve the function I have written in my original post as it is part of a larger, more complicated integral that I cannot solve until I have figured this part out.

Comment: Do you think you could write a short primer on exactly how the program is supposed to work? I think that would lower the bar considerably for programmers who just want to verify that your program is doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: This might be a question for math.stackexchange.com. My first idea for numerically integrating this function would be to perform a transformation of variables to make the domain into something more tractable, like the entire R2 plane. Then use a quadrature scheme (see, e.g., https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2004962).